# How to disable "RemoteDependencyData" in Microsoft Application Insights via Javascript SDK?

Tags: azure-application-insights, appinsights

The RemoteDependencyData is sent by default even if events are not tracked. Is there a way to disable RemoteDependencyData of Microsoft Application Insights via JavaScript SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

RemoteDependencyData events are collected each time your application makes Ajax requests.

You can disable autocollection here through `disableAjaxTracking: true` OR `maxAjaxCallsPerView: 0`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Yes. Setting disableAjaxTracking to true stops RemoteDependencyData events. But Now I am getting something new. PageviewData and PageviewPerformanceData are tracked as seen from the network log. But I am not tracking page view. So this happens automatically too. Is there a way to control this by adding some parameters in configuration as like above ?